# Change only one specific tableView row height

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, row-height

I'm looking for a way to change a specific row in my tableView.

I'm using a Notification to check when I do an action in my cell. According to the answer, my goal is to display the next row.

By default, my cell have this property.

```
if (indexPath.row == 5){
    tableView.rowHeight = 0.0
}

if (indexPath.row == 6){
    tableView.rowHeight = 0.0
}

return cell
```

My goal when I'm in my notification is to change the row height value for the fifth row.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks but No because I would like to change the height of the row directly from my notification, not in the tableView function

Comment: You need to change cell row on click action?

Comment: Yes it's my goal.
In my app, I'm using radio items so if I choose one specific item, I want to display the next one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Set<IndexPath>` and your tableView delegate methods to achieve this.

Say you have a set of selected index paths `selectedIndexPaths` and heights `largeHeight` and `normalHeight`.  Your `heightForRow` func could look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heigthForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    guard !selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) else {
        return largeHeight
    }

    return normalHeight
}
```

Then you could change the height dynamically the following way:

```
/// Convenience method for selecting an index path
func select(indexPath: IndexPath, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil){
    selectedIndexPaths.insert(indexPath)
    tableView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }, completion: completion)
}
```

In your tableView delegate, you could call this method in didSelect:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    select(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Do the same if you have a method responding to your notification (assuming you placed your indexPath in your notification's userInfo, under the key "indexPathKey"):

```
func notifiedShouldEnlargeRow(aNotification: Notification) {
    guard let indexPath = aNotification.userInfo["indexPathKey"] as? IndexPath else { return }
    select(indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

For reference, look at [performBatchUpdates(_:completion)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates) and [reloadRows(at:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/rowanimation).

Comment: Not all of the code was necessary but I found the solution with 
```self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```
Thank you

Comment: Just thought I'd drop a full working example. :)  Glad it helped!